# Could not find or load main class java maven

Tags: java, maven

это структура проекта
[image: структура проекта]

```
<build>
        <plugins>
                 <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
<archive>
<manifest>
<mainClass>
example.Solution</mainClass>
</manifest>
</archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

это pom.xml

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: Владислав
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_101
Main-Class: example.Solution
```

MANIFEST.MF

в классе Solution самый примитивный и рабочий код.
Почему выскакивает ошибка Could not find or load main class?

Comment: потому что класс у вас, очевидно, `main.java.example.Solution`

Comment: @etki да,так и есть.проблема решена. Спасибо Вам.